# Why am I getting nullpointer error?

Tags: servlets, nullpointerexception

To retrieve cookies from browsert, I wrote a simple function `dispcookies()`. When I compile, I got `nullpointerException` and then I just copied that code from `dispcookies()` and put in `processRequest()` that time I didn't get the error why it happens.

```
HttpServletRequest request;
HttpServletResponse response;
PrintWriter out=null;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String phone=request.getParameter("phone");    
        Cookie cname=new Cookie("name",name);
        Cookie cphone=new Cookie("phone",phone);            
        response.addCookie(cname);
        response.addCookie(cphone);
        out.println("here ok");
        dispcookies ();  
    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
        out.println(E);
    }
}

void dispcookies () throws IOException
{
    Cookie[] cookies;
    Cookie cookie;
    cookies=request.getCookies();
    if(cookies!=null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++)
        {
            cookie=cookies[i];
        out.println("cookie name"+cookie.getName());
        out.println("cookie name"+cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
    else
    {
    out.println("no foumd cooke ");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: if you post the stack trace we can tell you what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At void `dispcookies ()` you are trying to access to a property of the attribute request. **WARNING: This request IS NOT THE SAME that the input parameter of the `processRequest` method**. `dispcookies` doesn't have visibility over these input parameter, only can see the attribute `HttpServletRequest` defined at the beginning of the class and this attribute has not been initialized so every access to it will cause a null pointer exception.

If you want to access to the processRequest' request input parameter you must change the `dispcookies` signature to accept this object as input parameter and use it.

By the way:

```
cookies=request.getCookies();
if(cookies!=null) { 
    for(int i=0;i ...
```

could cause a null pointer exception because `Cookies[]` can be not null but empty and you are accessing to its zero position without checking the emptyness of the array.

Comment: so what should I do exactly guys I am new in this help me plz.

Comment: 1) Remove useless HttpServletRequest request attribute that you declared at the first line
2) Modify dispcookies method to accept a HttpServletRequest input parameter
3) Invoke dispcookies method using HttpServletRequest request that comes as processRequest method input parameter (this is the ONLY request you need)
4) Try it, enjoy it and vote me ;)